# Hadoop Multinode Cluster : Connection failed with slave node

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'm trying to use my `Hadoop Multinode Cluster` :

- 1 Namenode (master)
- 2 Datanodes (slave1 & slave2)

I would like to make some tests with `MapReduce` but I'm getting an issue and I don't find anywhere to solve this one.

I uploaded to my `HDFS` a file called **data.txt**

I created both files : **mapper.py** and **reducer.py** which are stored in my hadoop local repository.

I executed this command :

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.5/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.5.jar 
-mapper /usr/local/hadoop/mapper.py -reducer /usr/local/hadoop/reducer.py 
-input hdfs://master:54310/data.txt -output hdfs://master:54310/output.txt
```

In my Terminal, I have this issue :

```
packageJobJar: [/tmp/hadoop-unjar6386556681700293769/] [] /tmp/streamjob2613722562503212451.jar tmpDir=null
18/03/16 15:45:02 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/172.30.10.64:8050
18/03/16 15:45:03 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/172.30.10.64:8050
18/03/16 15:45:05 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
18/03/16 15:45:05 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
18/03/16 15:45:05 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1521211085961_0001
18/03/16 15:45:06 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1521211085961_0001
18/03/16 15:45:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1521211085961_0001/
18/03/16 15:45:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1521211085961_0001
18/03/16 15:45:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1521211085961_0001 running in uber mode : false
18/03/16 15:45:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/03/16 15:45:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1521211085961_0001_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1754)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/hadoop/mapper.py": error=2, Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 24 more

18/03/16 15:45:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1521211085961_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
```

So I looked to : http://172.30.10.64:8088/proxy/application_1521211085961_0001/

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /proxy/application_1521211085961_0001/. Reason:

    Connection to http://slave1:8088 refused

Caused by:

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://slave1:8088 refused
```

It's very strange because my both datanodes are well-configured (I can ping, I can connect thanks to ssh, ...)

[image]

### My configuration :

#### First step :

/etc/hosts are good on each node :

- 172.30.10.64 master
- 172.30.10.72 slave1
- 172.30.10.62 slave2

#### Second step :

/etc/hostname are good on each node :

- master for master node
- slave1 for slave1 node
- slave2 for slave2 node

#### Third step :

The command `jps` gives me on master node :

```
4131 NameNode
4501 ResourceManager
5049 Jps
4347 SecondaryNameNode
```

and on slave nodes :

```
2357 DataNode
2491 NodeManager
2957 Jps
```

**So why my namenode get refused connection to slave1 ?**

**EDIT:**

I installed Hadoop 2 years ago on Proxmox with 3 VM's in order to simulate each node and I had NAT mode enabled.

Now, I'm working with VMWare VSphere and I don't have NAT mode.

My issue could comes from this option ??

Comment: Python script is calling http://slave1:8088. How do you know that slave1 is up on port 8088

Answer (score 0):

From your jps output, I see no JobTracker on master and no TaskTracker on slave. I think you might have forgotten to run bin/start-mapred.sh on your master and if you have run it already then I think you need to check/provide logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-slave.log on your slaves for errors.
Also checkout this [post](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) for setting up hadoop multi-node cluster 
step by step.